# Can ZSH auto-insert matching delimiters?

Tags: shell, zsh

Does zsh have a way to auto-close matching delimiters as I type, ala textmate, [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) in vim, or [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens)/electric-pair-mode in emacs?

For example (where `|` is the cursor):

- `git commit -m |` => <kbd>"</kbd> => `git commit -m "|"`
- `echo $|` => <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> => `echo $((|))`

`edit-command-line` is a fine alternative (letting you edit your command with your $EDITOR), but this is one nicety I'd love to have straight on the prompt, especially when typing regex or piping elisp to emacs.

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html Write your own widget if you'd like to. Pretty easy.

Comment: @4ae1e1 That's perfect! All my +1's. I've [hacked together a working example](https://gist.github.com/hlissner/ca6696f80c8ae889a10b). A little polish and I should have something to turn into a plugin (and an answer to this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a [simple plugin called zsh-autopair](https://github.com/hlissner/zsh-autopair) to provide auto-closing (and deleting) of delimiters in zsh.

Thanks to @4ae1e1 for showing me the Zsh line editor.